# Doing maths in Drools and Optaplanner

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I'm using optaplanner in conjunction with Drools, and I have a Drools rule:

```
rule "No student double booked"
    when
        ScheduledLesson($timeslot : timeslot, $student : lesson.student)
        ScheduledLesson(timeslot == $timeslot, lesson.student == $student)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

This works fine.

I want to make sure students don't have lessons back to back:

```
rule "Student does not have contiguous lessons"
    when
        ScheduledLesson($timeslot : timeslot, $student : lesson.student)
        ScheduledLesson(timeslot == $timeslot + 1, lesson.student == $student)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

Note the `timeslot == $timeslot + 1` piece in the 4th line.  This gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error evaluating constraint 'timeslot == $timeslot + 1' in [Rule "Student does not have contiguous lessons" filename]
```

This seems at odds with the [Drools documentation which touches on maths](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html).  Where am I going wrong, and how can I implement this rule in Drools?

`ScheduledLesson` looks like this:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class ScheduledLesson {
    public Lesson lesson;

    public Lesson getLesson() {
        return this.lesson;
    }

    public void setLesson(Lesson lesson) {
        this.lesson = lesson;
    }

    public Integer timeslot;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"timeslot"})
    public Integer getTimeslot() {
        return this.timeslot;
    }
    public void setTimeslot(Integer timeslot) {
        this.timeslot = timeslot;
    }

    public Room room;
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"room"})
    public Room getRoom() {
        return this.room;
    }
    public void setRoom(Room room) {
        this.room = room;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share how `ScheduledLesson` and `timeslot` looks like ? I can't replicate this error, so could it be that `$timeslot + 1 `is an invalid statement as timeslot is not a numerical datatype ? Another thing could be a potential need for paranthesis around your addition, e.g. ($timeslot + 1), but I am not sure if that is the issue here.

Comment: Hi @k88 thanks for your reply.  I have updated with ScheduledLesson.  `$timeslot` is an `Integer`, which handles simple addition just like a primitive. It's an `Integer` rather than an `int` because Optaplanner needs to know whether it's been set or not, and `int` isn't nullable.  Parentheses gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `ScheduledLesson.getTimeslot()` returns an instance `Timeslot`, not `int`.

1. In java, add a `ScheduledLesson.getTimeslotIndex()` method that does
   `return timeslot.getIndex()`
2. Then in de DRL do: `ScheduledLesson(timeslotIndex == $timeslot.getIndex() + 1, ...`

Comment: Hmm in my case `ScheduledLesson.getTimeslot()` returns an `Integer`, because it needs to be nullable so Optaplanner knows if it's been set or not.  Could it be this?

Comment: Yes, you should start with a null check first: `ScheduleLesson(timeslot != null, timeslot +1 == ...)`